# Need tool for application suite`s manual / wiki creation

Tags: windows, wiki

If this is a wrong place to ask, please point me to the right one :)

I am going to create a manual for software suite / system i have created. it is a large scale suite, containing several modules with distinctive set of functions each. Some functionality is accessible from more than one module. Other may be required to.

Word document per module is not an ideal solution for this one, due to number of pictures / screenshots i intend to embed in the page and lack of proper navigation.

Is there a tool, that will allow me to create some type of manual with wiki-ish look / feel / navigation and scalability

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Should have mentioned it, sorry.
It has to be an offline repository, there is a part of consumers that have occasional internet access only

Comment: Why not a wiki?

Comment: It is an online tool ,or am i mistaken?

Comment: Some wikis can be implemented on a single computer and all can be provided on an intranet.

Comment: Could you possibly point me to the site i can read up on it?

Comment: Check out https://www.wikimatrix.org. I think DokuWiki is great and especially good for documentation. https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki To run locally check out: https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:dokuwiki_on_a_stick

Comment: Also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_wiki. I've also installed MoinMoin locally and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) to build an offline knowledge database composed of small articles you can tag categorize search and filter.

It is browser based but does not require internet connection, and can easily be distributed as a single file, and easily opened on most platforms with a web browser (including mobile). May not be suited if you require embedding lots of images into the single file, but images can be distributed as external files and included in a zipped archive.

If that is not suited you can use some sort of ebook format to build a single file manual with all images and dependencies included, and with a structured index.

[Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/) is a open source ebook editor

[Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) is a similar application with equivalent features in a commercial model.

[Treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/) is a sort of outliner database hybrid that can be used as a hierarchical document builder and export the output as PDF or distribute the originals in the original format if requiring a desktop application is not an issue.

[HelpNDoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/) is a dedicated help and documentation creation tool to create Microsoft format CHF HTML Help files.

[Precision Helper](http://www.be-precision.com) is a similar application offering much of the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the classic Wiki service: http://www.wikia.com/Special:CreateNewWiki